# Comparing a negative number in bash script. Unsure what error means

Tags: bash, macos, negative-number

I am trying to compare that an immediate is in bounds and I cannot see why it is not working. Have tried putting the variables in "" still same error and also using (()) with <> as operands. The negative number is -9 and the error I receive is:

```
./valsplit.sh: line 89: [[: −9: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "??9")
```

This is my script:

```
checkImmediate(){
lowerBound=-32768
upperBound=32767
if [[ $immediate -lt $lowerBound || $immediate -gt $upperBound ]]; then
    hasErrors=1
    errors+=("Out of bounds immediate. Immediates range between −32768 and 32767.")
fi
}
```

I am using OSX.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Weird, on my machine I get no errors with the same code. I set immediate=-9 and I'm working on OS X too

Comment: Try putting the variables in quotes. So "$immediate" and "$lowerBound" etc

Comment: Inian -9, mentioned above :) PMonti thanks for taking time

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned tried this Raman

Comment: `immediate=-9
    lowerBound=-32768
    upperBound=32767
    if [[ $immediate -lt $lowerBound || $immediate -gt $upperBound ]]; then
        echo "out"
    else
        echo "in"
    fi`

This flawlessly works for me. Try executing this piece alone, if you get no errors too, it means the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @MitchFeaver: Are you copy pasting stuff from a Windows machine, did you check for `CRLF` type endings? can do you `file <script-name>` and post what you are seeing there?

Comment: Seemed to run on linux and runs without errors. Very very strange. Thank you for your speedy replies!

Comment: @Inian I will hopefully get another chance to run again on the same machine when my colleague returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is fine, it's your values that are wrong. Here's an example:

```
$ var='1 –9' # this is a Unicode dash
$ [[ $var -lt 5 ]]
-bash: [[: 1 –9: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "–9")
```

The value from your posted error has a Unicode dash, and this should be immediately obvious if you look at `set -x` output.

Ensure that all your variable are integers without special characters. (Note that `echo` and visual inspection is not enough to determine this since not all characters are printable or distinguishable).

Comment: You sir are an absolute hero!! Great spot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As everyone said this is working, for me too (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16), MacOS Sierra 10.12.4).

Try this

```
if [ $immediate -lt $lowerBound -o $immediate -gt $upperBound ]; then
    command
fi
```

Comment: Thank you @theofanis. Using the -o is also cleaner! works on other machines which was the strangest part. Glad it isnt a problem with syntax though. Thanks again